# Hibernate could not initialize proxy - no Session even with Eager loading

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a `Spring-MVC` application in which I am using Hibernate as the ORM tool. I am adding chat functionality to the application and when I try to add a chat message, I am getting **Hibernate's No session error**. I checked various solutions on the net, and they suggest to use Eager method, but I already have it as eager loading, and still I am getting the error. I am posting the code, kindly have a look.

**User Model** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userinfo")
public class User implements UserDetails{

// I am using 2 foreign keys in the database to store the sender and receiver id for the message.

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user2", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Messages> messages1 = new HashSet<Messages>();

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user3", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Messages> messages2 = new HashSet<Messages>();
}
```

**Messages Model** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conversation")
public class Messages {
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userinfo_id")
    private User user3;
}
```

**MessagesDAOImpl** :

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addMessage(User sender, User receiver, Messages messages) {

   @M.Denium : When I remove the below 4 lines, it works. Can you please tell me why? 
          session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

 /*  int id = sender.getId();
    int id2 = receiver.getId();
    User sender1 = (User) session.get(User.class,id);
    User receiver1 = (User) session.get(User.class,id2);*/
   /* sender.getMessages1().add(messages);
    receiver.getMessages2().add(messages);*/
    messages.setConversationtimestamp(new Date());
    messages.setUser2(sender);
    messages.setUser3(receiver);
    session.merge(messages);
    session.flush();
    return true;
}
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Messages> listMessagesForUser(User user) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
       /* if(session == null){
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        } else{
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }*/
        int id = user.getId();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Messages as m where m.user2.id=:id");
        query.setParameter("id",id);
        List<Messages> messagesList= query.list();
        session.flush();
        return messagesList;
    }
```

**MessageController**:

```
@Controller
public class MessageController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/messages/add/{receiverid}")
    public String sendMessages(@ModelAttribute("messages")Messages messages, @PathVariable("receiverid") int receiverid, Model model){
        User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        User user1 = userService.getUserById(receiverid);
        this.messageService.addMessage(user,user1,messages);
        model.addAttribute("messages", new Messages());
        model.addAttribute("listMessages", this.messageService.listMessagesForUser(user));
        return "messages";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/messages/list")
    public String listMessages(@ModelAttribute("messages") Messages messages, Model model){
        User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        model.addAttribute("messages", new Messages());
        model.addAttribute("listMessages", this.messageService.listMessagesForUser(user));
        return "messages";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, any pointers are welcome, If there is any more information required, kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `openSession` to get a session, use `getCurrentSession` always, else you are opening unmanaged sessions. The problem is you ar retrieving the `User` and then pass it on. The session that was used to retrieve the user was already closed. You should move this logic into a single method that is `@Transactional` you now have business logic in your controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Thank you, I managed to solve the problem by removing code from MessagesDAOImpl and working on already existing entities in session. I just have one question, what business logic do I have right now in Controller?

Comment: Retrieving the users should, imho, be part of your service method (which you also do) instead of in your controller. Which would also make it easier to test (and would save you smoe queries probably :) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum  You are right, I don't know why I am retrieving the receiver user in Controller... If possible, can you please frame your answer as a question, also, I am editing my post to show what I remove from MessageDAOImpl, which made it work..I would be really thankful if you explain me why it worked when I removed that code, editing my post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding @Transactional on your methods, spring will take care of create/close the hibernate session and create/commit/rollback of the transactions. 
So remove this code in "addMessage()" method

```
if( session == null) {
    session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
}else {
    session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

and remove this line in "listMessagesForUser()" method

```
session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Instead just get the current session with "sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()" and use it within the method.
    Also you need to enable transactional management by adding **@EnableTransactionManagement** on your @Configuration bean.

You can read all about [spring transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Comment: I tried what you said, I get NullPointerExceptions. Do you want me to post any code for you, happy to do so and to learn. Thank you very much.

Comment: In "listMessagesForUser" use getCurrentSession(), instead of openSession()

Comment: Ok, I did that, I had removed all the code, my bad. Thanks.